# TLS on exchange

Tags: tls, exchange-2007

Basically I need to sign all emails going out of exchange 2007 on one domain while leaving all others unsigned.

Can anyone give me a quick how to or point me in the right direction for some tutorials

Comment: For a start – TLS has nothing to do with signing email messages (except for the X.509 certificate format that it shares with the S/MIME signing/encryption protocol). Could you clarify if you're looking for S/MIME, PGP, DKIM, or really just want to encrypt communications using TLS?

Comment: We would be using a x.509v3 certificate. From what I gather its mainly for encrypting email traffic between two email servers?

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of certificate that TLS uses – assuming you have one cert for the whole server. It encrypts traffic between you and the next hop (the sender's or recipient's server), but does not attach signatures to message data.